# Compiling SDL2 with Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, sdl-2, mingw-w64

I have been trying to set up a C++ environment for Visual Studio Code which has worked till I tried to use SDL2 with it. The compiler I am using is the "g++" one that is included in mingw64. I downloaded the SDL2.09 development library for mingw. I copied and pasted all of the header files into the include folder(it is the right one as I get no errors about unable to find the header file) and pasted the libs into the libs folder(the compiler is also able to find them). I also copied and pasted the dll into the directory in which I was compiling the code. Then, I built the program and kept on getting errors. Depending on the order of the libraries, sometimes it was that there are multiple definitions of 'main' or something about winMain. Sometimes it said that a bunch of SDL things were undefined. However, each time I did run it what was consistent was that when I used SDL_init or any SDL function it would say the reference was undefined.

I have already included adding the mingw32 library along with the other libraries. I have also tried rearranging the order of the libraries which gets varying results of different error messages, but nothing successful. I have tried doing the same sort of setup in the eclipse ide to the same error messages.

```
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "g++_sdl2_build",
      "command": "D:\\Coding\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "args": [
        "-lmingw32",
        "-lSDL2main",
        "-lSDL2",
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "-w"
      ],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "shell",
      "label": "g++.exe build active file",
      "command": "D:\\Coding\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "${file}",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "D:\\Coding\\mingw64\\bin"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

^^^ is my tasks.json file where the build file is.

```
#include <sdl.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *args[])
{
      if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
      {
            cout << "SDL init failed" << endl;
            return 1;
      }

      cout << "SDL init successful" << endl;

      SDL_Quit();
      return 0;
}
```

^^is my cpp file that I have attempted to compile

One error after attempted build:

```
D:/Coding/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/SDL2main.lib(x64/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[main]+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
D:/Coding/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
C:\Users\YARHAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccBO9BFb.o: In function `SDL_main':
d:/Coding/Github/cpp_coding/SDL_testing/sdl_test.cpp:8: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
d:/Coding/Github/cpp_coding/SDL_testing/sdl_test.cpp:16: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Other errors after switching the order of SDL2 and SDL2main libraries :

```
D:/Coding/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/SDL2main.lib(x64/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[main]+0x0): multiple definition of `main'
D:/Coding/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/libmingw32.a(lib64_libmingw32_a-crt0_c.o):crt0_c.c:(.text.startup+0x0): first defined here
D:/Coding/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/SDL2main.lib(x64/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[OutOfMemory]+0x1a): undefined reference to `SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox'
D:/Coding/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/SDL2main.lib(x64/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[main_getcmdline]+0xe4): undefined reference to `SDL_SetMainReady'
D:/Coding/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/SDL2main.lib(x64/Release/SDL_windows_main.obj):(.text[main_getcmdline]+0x131): undefined reference to `SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox'
C:\Users\YARHAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccOsF7gq.o: In function `SDL_main':
d:/Coding/Github/cpp_coding/SDL_testing/sdl_test.cpp:8: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
d:/Coding/Github/cpp_coding/SDL_testing/sdl_test.cpp:16: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

Best possible error case is when in the build file I do not include the mingw32 library as well as having the order of libraries being SDL2main and SDL2. The errors that result are :

```
C:\Users\YARHAR~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccjAeK0z.o: In function `SDL_main':
d:/Coding/Github/cpp_coding/SDL_testing/sdl_test.cpp:8: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
d:/Coding/Github/cpp_coding/SDL_testing/sdl_test.cpp:16: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

I hope to actually be able to compile the program successfully and for SDL2 to actually work.

Comment: Libraries have to be specified *after* files that uses them, so your `"${file}"` have to be before any library. Also `-w` is the worst idea ever - you want more warnings (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`), not none at all.